# Distinct By LINQ The Best Way And quickly

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

want to know unique have by date
In other words I will not use it twice one IP address and I would like the field of date
What I have done up to now it worked

```
db.Exposures.DistinctBy(d => d.UserIP).Select(o =>o.ExpouserDate).ToList();
```

But it took too much time is there a better way 
Forgiveness for my English and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var res = db.Exposures
            .GroupBy(ex => ex.UserIp)
            .Select(gr => gr.Max(x = >x.ExpouserDate));
```

Comment: this is "Distinct" by two parameters Date And IP
but I wants To "Distinct" by The IP And Select THE DATE

Comment: @Yitzhakor50 So let that we have 50 IP and 30 are unique of them you want those 30 IPs? If that's true, what would be the date? do you want the  last date of each of them?

Comment: This is your real answer      db.Exposures
            .GroupBy(exe => exe.ExpouserDate)
            .Select(gr =>
            new {
                Date = gr.Key,
                DistinctIps = gr.Select(x => x.UserIP).Distinct()
            }).Select(o => o.Date).ToList();

Comment: So you don't need to select the ips? correct? you just want the distinct exposure dates?

Comment: Yes I do not have the IP

Comment: @Yitzhakor50 Please check my updated answer. I may got what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120356/discussion-between-yitzhak-or50-and-christos).